# Overwrite Property of Default Variable in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to figure out if there is any way to overwrite a property of a variable declared in defaults by group_vars.
The exact issue is, that I automate the deployment of MySQL servers, and I created the default configuration options in the playbook's defaults as a list of key-value pairs, but sometimes some value needs to be changed, but not necessarily all.

I have the following YAML code in **defaults/main/mysql_config.yml** and this is parsed by a Jinja2 template into my.cnf file.:

```
performance_tuning:
  query_cache_type: 1
  query_cache_size: 512M
  query_cache_limit: 2M
  query_cache_strip_comments: 1
  thread_pool_size: "{{ ansible_processor_vcpus  }}"
  wait_timeout: 15
  interactive_timeout: 15
  max_connections: 151
```

And I would like to change one of these properties in the **group_vars/all** without repeating the whole code.

I tried the following, but seems it is not the way to do it, the template still uses the default value:

```
performance_tuning.query_cache_size: 128M
```

Also, if I add the *performance_tuning* variable to group_vars with that only one property, then it obviously deploys that only one property into the configuration file:

```
performance_tuning:
  query_cache_size: 128M
```

Jinja2 template:

```
{% if performance_tuning is defined and performance_tuning|length %}
{% for key, value in performance_tuning.items() %}
{{ key }}={{ value }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: If i get this correctly this might be related to variable precedence in ansible. From where are you looking to replace the value ? `host vars` or `extr vars`

Comment: Wanna use the Ansible code as a kind of IaC, so I would not use extra vars, but trying to change the variable from the inventory group_vars/all file for a certain cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could do this several ways. Here are few of them.

**1. Logic within Jinga template, this is very simple**

```
{% for x in performance_tuning %}
{% if x == 'query_cache_size' and env == 'dev'%}
{{x}} : 128M
{% elif x == 'query_cache_size' and env == 'uat'%}
{{x}} : 256M
{% else %}
{{ x }} : {{performance_tuning[x]}}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**2. Through variables**

Different variables for different clusters or different environments.

```
env: "dev"

query_cache_dev_size: "128M"
query_cache_uat_size: "256M"
query_cache_prod_size: "512M"


performance_tuning:
  query_cache_size: "{{ vars['query_cache_'+ env + '_size'] }}"
  ...
  ...
```

Something like this.

Like I said there are several other ways. Hope this helps.

**Edited**
**3.Using group_vars**

Like you said it only loads one configuration if we include the parent and child. But I found a way around it, maybe this helps.

Your normal `vars file`

```
performance_tuning:
  query_cache_type: 1
  query_cache_size: 512M
  query_cache_limit: 2M
  query_cache_strip_comments: 1
  thread_pool_size: "{{ ansible_processor_vcpus  }}"
  wait_timeout: 15
  interactive_timeout: 15
  max_connections: 151
```

Your group_vars/all

```
---
query_cache_size: "128M"
```

Your Jinga template should have a if condition to pick the normal `query_cache_size` from group_vars, something like this

```
{% for x in performance_tuning %}
{% if x == 'query_cache_size'%}
{{x}} : {{query_cache_size}}
{% else %}
{{ x }} : {{performance_tuning[x]}}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

So when the loop iterates, it keeps checking if the key is `query_cache_size` then it will pick the normal variable defined in `group_vars` which you might already know by looking at the template.

Hope this helps.

**Edit(Improvised 3rd method)**

Based on the comments, I can suggest something. Again it is hackie, not the concrete answer you might be looking for.

`vars file`

```
performance_tuning:
  query_cache_type: 1
  query_cache_size: 512M
  query_cache_limit: 2M
  query_cache_strip_comments: 1
  thread_pool_size: 10
  wait_timeout: 15
  interactive_timeout: 15
  max_connections: 151
```

`group_vars`

```
new_performance_tuning:
  query_cache_type: 10
  query_cache_size: 256M
  query_cache_limit: 12M
```

`Jinga template`

```
{% for x in performance_tuning %}
{% if x in new_performance_tuning %}
{{ x }} : {{ new_performance_tuning[x] }}
{% else %}
{{ x }} : {{performance_tuning[x]}}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This is more logical if you don't want to use `if` condition for every variable you want to reuse.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these solves my problem, as in my case I do not separate the clusters like that. More production servers can be deployed with different configurations, that's why I would like to overwrite in the group_vars and the values varies depending on the RAM size of the VMs in each cluster.

Comment: @TamásJuhász, Cool! I found a way around your approach, I added the same to the answer check the edited section. Hope this helps, let me know for more information.

Comment: Ah yep, this would work with one variable, but the query_cache_size is just an example, it could be any other from the list, that has to be changed in order to tune the performance of a certain cluster. Or I have to create the 'if' part for every possible performance_tuning property, but there is still possbility to add more properties to the list, in that case template should be updated again too.

Comment: @TamásJuhász, added an improvised method based on your comment, hope that helps. Let me know if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Final solution based on @BinaryBulletin's suggestions:
defaults/mariadb_config.yml

```
default_performance_tuning:
  query_cache_type: 1
  query_cache_size: 128M
  query_cache_limit: 2M
  query_cache_strip_comments: 1
  thread_pool_size: "{{ ansible_processor_vcpus  }}"
  wait_timeout: 15
  interactive_timeout: 15
  max_connections: 151
```

group_vars/all

```
cluster_performance_tuning:
  query_cache_size: 64M
```

templates/my.cnf.j2

```
[mysqld]
{% for key, value in default_performance_tuning.items() %}
{% if cluster_performance_tuning is defined %}
{% if key in cluster_performance_tuning %}
{{ key }}={{ cluster_performance_tuning[key] }}
{% else %}
{{ key }}={{ value }}
{% endif %}
{% else %}
{{ key }}={{ value }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Template picks up the 'query_cache_size: 64M' from the cluster_performance_tuning variable properly.